# Reduce size of Texture2D on iOS in Unity3D (cannot use mipmap)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I wonder if there is a better way to reduce the quality of Texture2D. My situation here is that I want to send a captured photo to my server on iOS, but the captured photo size is too big, which takes so much time to get response from server. For some reason, the texture2D got from camera do not support mipmap (in which I can getPixels(2) to directly reduce the size). To still use mipmap, I have to create a Texture2D (tmp) and copy it from captured photo, and then create another texture2D to get high mipmap level of tmp. But it costs to much memory on iOS, which may cause crashes. Any idea that can solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

```
pixels = new Color[(int)(photo.width * photo.height / 16)];
pixels2 = photo.GetPixels();
for(int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; ++i){
    pixels[i] = pixels2[16*i];
}
tempPhoto = new Texture2D((int)photo.width / 4, (int)photo.height / 4);
tempPhoto.SetPixels(pixels);
tempPhoto.Apply();
```

Should this be okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by "hard coding setting pixels"

```
pixels = new Color[(int)(photo.width * photo.height / 16)];
pixels2 = photo.GetPixels();
for(int i = 0; i < (int)photo.height / 4; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < (int)photo.width / 4; ++j){
        pixels[i*(int)(photo.width/4) + j] = pixels2[i*4*(int)(photo.width) + j*4];
    }
}

tempPhoto = new Texture2D((int)photo.width / 4, (int)photo.height / 4);
tempPhoto.SetPixels(pixels);
tempPhoto.Apply();
```

But I think I still need to carefully care the usage of Color[] array, I cannot use "using" for Color[] since it not supports "IDisposable". But according to [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingAutomaticMemoryManagement.html), it seems Unity automatically handles it for us if I set both "pixels" and "pixels2" to null after using it.

Comment: If are you creating that new texture just for sending, maybe could send the byte or color32 array instead, so no need the last 3 lines on that script..

Comment: @mgear Yes u r right, thanks for reminding me of that.